# How to get date picked from a date field on a web page designed using vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, datefield

```
DateField fromDate = new DateField();
fromDate.setCaption("From Date:");
fromDate.setDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

How can i get fromDate value?

Answer (score 0):

With `getValue`:

```
Date fromDateValue = (Date) fromDate.getValue();
```